# Discussion Board can't reply to some posts but can for others

Tags: discussion-board

I have created an OOTB discussion boards but for some users there is an issue with replying to some of the discussions. In some cases they get they don't have permissions to post a reply but in other cases they are able to reply successfully. What could be causing this issue as i am a bit confused?